# How to cancel a data based to the current time?

Tags: sql

I created an application for booking tennis lessons. I need to cancel the line in my database when the reservation is exceeded.
I found a way to cancel it based on the current day but not the current time.

At the moment I have this:
$sql = "DELETE FROM events WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),date_event) > 0";

But that doesn't take into account the time.

Comment: Check the docs of the RDBMS you are using for DATEDIFF to see what additional parameter is to use to get the result more precisely than day - the default I guess.

Comment: Do you mean the additional parameter "hour" like this:$sql = "DELETE FROM events WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, NOW(),date_event) > 0"; I tried it too but it's doesn't work anymore. PHPMydmin write "incorrect parameter"

Comment: Why not just this?: DELETE FROM events WHERE NOW() > date_event;

Comment: congratulations ! Thank you for your help

Comment: Still, the RDBMS tag would be useful, and the title's correction, because not the cancellation is the question, but getting the time difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM events WHERE NOW() > date_event;
```

Comment: It would be more useful to know why the DATEDIFF can not give the time difference, however first the question needs to be updated as I commented above and might be obvious from the technology used - still, without the explanation the correct way of coding it is just half of the story.